# How do I have DeleteObject() invoked on hBitmap other than by using P/Invoke?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, pinvoke, hbitmap

I'm dealing with code that goes something like this (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546121/57428))

```
using (var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(1000, 1000)) 
{
    IntPtr hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap(); 
    var source = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
        hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
```

and MSDN says that whenever I call `Bitmap.GetHbitmap()` I have to call `DeleteObject()` on the `hBitmap` to release the unmanaged resources.

All the answers I've seen and MSDN say I have to P/Invoke the `DeleteObject()` function. This looks a bit insane because I obtained the `hBitmap` without P/Invoke and now I suddenly need to use P/Invoke to proper get rid of it.

Is there indeed no other way except P/Invoke to have `DeleteObject()` called for my `hBitmap`?

Comment: They make [`DeleteObject()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/misc/GDI/DeviceContext.cs,0ec286748b35196a), which needs [`GdiObjectType.Bitmap`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/misc/GDI/GdiObjectType.cs,1f181904379350ac,references) as parameter. But they are `internal`...

Comment: I don't think there is other way... Even [FromHbitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.drawing.image.fromhbitmap.aspx) creates copy and requires `DeleteObject` on original.  But the whole point of obtaining HBITMAP is to do interop - not sure if one additional  method is soo bad (even shown in the link you've posted) .

Comment: What's the problem with having to P/Invoke? You've already had to pass the barrier to entry (`UnmanagedCode`) when you called `GetHBitmap`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The problem is I suddenly need to craft a proxy method decorated with `DllImport` which doesn't look neat.

Comment: You've already taken on interop by calling GetHBitmap. In for a penny, in for a pound.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I've called a Bitmap.GetHBitmap() method which was declared in the .NET Framework and now I suddenly have to craft a proxy just to get rid of what that method returned. This is kinda weird.

Comment: So don't call `GetHBitmap` then. Oh wait, you did that because you want to do some interop.....

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I pass `hBitmap` into `CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap()` which is also a method of a class in .NET Framework. I would be just as happy to `Bitmap` reference in there but for whatever reason that thing requires an `IntPtr` representing an unmanaged object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that there's any way to call `DeleteObject` from C# other than using p/invoke.

So, if you want to avoid this undesired trip into unmanaged code then you should avoid calling `GetHbitmap` in the first place. You can do that readily enough. You want to make a `BitmapSource`. Do that with a call to `BitmapSource.Create`.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are for ...

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private BitmapSource Bmp2BmpSrc(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
    BitmapSource bs;

    try
    {
        bs = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                hBitmap,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

    }   finally { DeleteObject(hBitmap); } 

    return bs;
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
private static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
```

hBitmap must be manually disposed of; otherwise, each call continues to consume memory until none is left. Apologies to the original content creator, I cannot find the link to the page I derived this from at the time.

Cheers